# css style class not changing

Tags: html, css

Okay so i'm really new. A few hours ago I set the style class "P" to

```
...// <Style>
          P {color:black, font-size: 16pt;}
...// </Style>
```

and i think it might have broken something! All my other lines of code are working but this one! I assumed it would just make every default new paragraph black 16pt... but its not letting me change the color.

the .need1 classes aren't being called properly and show up as the previous setting of black 16pt, not the .need1 class of centered, 24pt red, bold text.

Also, the Jfiddler kept tellng me that

```
</P>
```

as a close was improper so i removed them but should i put them back? I tried both ways already and it didn't solve the  issue.

```
    <STYLE>.

            .red1 {color: #ff0000}
            .orange1 {color: }
            .blue1
            .green1
            .need1 {font-size:24pt; color:red; font-weight: bold; text-align:center}
            .need2 {font-size:16pt; color:red;}
            .want {font-size:16pt; color:orange}
            .fun {font-size:14pt; color:green}
            .cata {font-size:20pt; color:black; font-weight: bold; text-decoration:underline; text-align: left}
            .specs1 {font-size:20pt; color:blue; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; text-decoration: underline}
            .specs2 {font-size:16pt; color: blue; text-align:center}
            .head {font-size:28pt; color:purple; text-align:center; 
                    text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold}
            .ex {font-size: 18; color:black; text-align: right}

            a:link    {color:blue; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
            a:visited {color:purple; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
            a:hover   {color:red; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:underline}
            a:active  {color:yellow; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:underline}
</STYLE>.

<P Class = "head"> TEXT
</P>

<P Class = "need1"> TEXT
    <BR>TEXT <span Class = "red1">TEXT</span> TEXT

    <BR>TEXT
    <BR>
    <BR>TEXT


<P Class = "cata">
    TEXT
</P>
<P>
    <BR>TEXT = <span class= "red1">RED</span>
    <BR>TEXT = ORANGE
    <BR>TEXT = 


<P Class = "head">
         TEXT[Jfiddle Screencapture][1]
</P>
```

[image]

Comment: why extra . after and before style tag?

Comment: Dont pit spaces between class="" this may help you

Comment: i wasn't sure how to input code in the text box on the website without it turning into code lol! i figured it out ctrl+k i think. Trying out your suggestions now, be back soon!

Comment: you have a lot mistakes in your code. please edit your question and tell us what you want.

Comment: please check this fiddle and let me know what issue you are facing. http://jsfiddle.net/Lsh7rt26/

Comment: Thank you leo! your code works, i think it may have been because i left class .orange1 undefined.

Comment: how do i close this question so no one else wastes time answering and mark leo as the fix/answer??

Comment: Thanks all, I see i have a lot more learning to do! Off to get some game time in before i dedicate tomorrow to studying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use !important

```
 P {color:black !important; font-size: 16pt !important;}
```

but first you have to correct mistakes in your code,Example: why you write "." after style, then you have to write ";" between css atributes not "."
this code after fixing

```css
 P {color:black !important; font-size: 16pt !important;}
            .red1 {color: #ff0000}
            .orange1 {color: }
            .blue1
            .green1
            .need1 {font-size:24pt; color:red; font-weight: bold; text-align:center}
            .need2 {font-size:16pt; color:red;}
            .want {font-size:16pt; color:orange}
            .fun {font-size:14pt; color:green}
            .cata {font-size:20pt; color:black; font-weight: bold; text-decoration:underline; text-align: left}
            .specs1 {font-size:20pt; color:blue; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; text-decoration: underline}
            .specs2 {font-size:16pt; color: blue; text-align:center}
            .head {font-size:28pt; color:purple; text-align:center; 
                    text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold}
            .ex {font-size: 18; color:black; text-align: right}

            a:link    {color:blue; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
            a:visited {color:purple; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
            a:hover   {color:red; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:underline}
            a:active  {color:yellow; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:underline}
```

```html
<P class = "head"> TEXT
</P>

<P Class = "need1"> TEXT
    <BR>TEXT <span Class = "red1">TEXT</span> TEXT

    <BR>TEXT
    <BR>
    <BR>TEXT


<P Class = "cata">
    TEXT
</P>
<P>
    <BR>TEXT = <span class= "red1">RED</span>
    <BR>TEXT = ORANGE
    <BR>TEXT = 


<P Class = "head">
         TEXT[Jfiddle Screencapture][1]
</P>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a semicolon after color, you have a comma instead.

P {color:black, font-size: 16pt;} change to P {color:black; font-size: 16pt;}

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Second and fourth p tag do not have matching closing tag same goes with BR tag change that it will work also remove "." After style opening and closing tag